# Unique elements in columns in csv file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a semicolon separated csv file which has the following form:

```
indx1; string1; char1; entry1 
indx2; string1; char2; entry2 
indx3; string2; char2; entry3 
indx4; string1; char1; entry4 
indx5; string3; char2; entry5
```

I want to get unique entries of the 1st and 2nd columns of this file in the form of a list (without using pandas or numpy). In particular these are the lists that I desire:

```
[string1, string2, string3] 
[char1, char2]
```

The order doesn't matter, and I would like the operation to be fast.

Presently, I am reading the file (say 'data.csv') using the command

```
with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
```

I am using python 2.7. What is the fastest way to achieve the functionality that I desire? I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you want unique combinations of `(col1, col2)` or all unique `col1` and all unique `col2` values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a list in Python with the unique values of a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441606/how-to-create-a-list-in-python-with-the-unique-values-of-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#set) to keep track of the already seen values in the needed columns. Since you say that the order doesn't matter, you could just convert the sets to lists after processing all rows:

```
import csv

col1, col2 = set(), set()

with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';', skipinitialspace=True)        
    for row in csv_reader:
        col1.add(row[1])
        col2.add(row[2])

print list(col1), list(col2)  # ['string1', 'string3', 'string2'] ['char2', 'char1']
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene, this was really helpful! Your solution worked. =)

Comment: Can we actually print them in order @Eugene Yarmash ?

Comment: @AlbionShala What do you mean by "print in order" ?

Comment: @EugeneYarmash I mean to print like `string1` `string2` `string3` like the way they are in the CSV

Answer (score 2):

This should work. You can use it as benchmark.

```
myDict1 = {}
myDict2 = {}
with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    for row in csv_reader:
        myDict1[row[1]] = 0
        myDict2[row[2]] = 0

x = myDict1.keys() 
y = myDict2.keys()
```

Comment: Thanks jimifiki, your solution was very helpful. It worked. =)

Comment: hi @jimifiki, I am getting the output like `dict_keys(['blla1','blla2'])` is there any way of printing only the keys without the `dict_keys`   so to print only `['blla1','blla2']`

Comment: sure @AlbionShala `list(myDict.keys())` constructs a list out of the dict_keys. So I would write `print(list(myDict.keys()))`, this should be fine. Have fun with Python's data structures ;-)

Comment: Actually in that way it prints all of them, so there are not only unique keys. What I did was just to iterate through `x` in your previous example, so `for y in x` ... `print(y)`. Thanks