# Trying to sort through a .csv file in Python (create list and remove duplicates)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .csv files with 9 columns. I need to get a list of the fifth column with no duplicates without using panda. The values in the column are product ID's, so things like "H0073456." There are over 1 million rows in the file. It is almost 4am and I'm getting sad. Help!

It seems like I need to generate a list format of the values in the column but I can't figure out how. Every time I tried I only ever successfully gotten the first value, or each character of the first value separated.

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as f_the_file:

    reader = csv.reader(f_the_file)

    for row in reader:

        print(row[4])
```

This gives me the whole column but still includes the duplicates. How do i filter them out??

The expected result is a list of the values in the 5th column of the .csv file with no duplicates. Right now the output includes duplicate values.

Comment: A sample of `myfile.csv`?

Comment: If you don't care about the ordering of the de-duped values, just construct a `set`.  If you do care about the ordering, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set

Comment: How about `list(set(row[4]))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a list in Python with the unique values of a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441606/how-to-create-a-list-in-python-with-the-unique-values-of-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look into the perfect object for you : set()

The set removes duplicates and let's you check if a value is in the set in O(1).

So your code should look like :

```
import csv
without_duplicates = set()
with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as f_the_file:

    reader = csv.reader(f_the_file)

    for row in reader:

        without_duplicates.add(row[4])
```

Comment: all of these answers seem like they work, but in the directions it says that i should have 13,000 values, and I am only getting 7,000. Could there be any reason why? I am trying to double check by counting the values in excel, but the file is so large it just keeps freezing my computer.

Comment: In the for-loop , append a list, just so you know how many were originaly in the file. If that number is less than 13K , than we have a problem ^^

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an empty set and then add elements to the set. This way you only keep on adding unique elements to the set. After you finish reading the the file you can convert it to list if you need so.

```
import csv

productID = set()
with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as f_the_file:
    reader = csv.reader(f_the_file)
    for row in reader:
        productID.add(row[4])

productID_list = list(productID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `set` comprehension for this:

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv') as f:
    product_ids = {row[4] for row in csv.reader(f)}
```

If you absolutely need a list, just call `product_ids = list(product_ids)` afterwards.

---

If you need to conserve the original order, (leaving a value where it first appeared), you should use the [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) `unique_everseen` (might require a lot of memory):

> ```
> from itertools import filterfalse
>
> def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
>     "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
>     # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
>     # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
>     seen = set()
>     seen_add = seen.add
>     if key is None:
>         for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
>             seen_add(element)
>             yield element
>     else:
>         for element in iterable:
>             k = key(element)
>             if k not in seen:
>                 seen_add(k)
>                 yield element
> ```

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv') as f:
    product_ids = list(unique_everseen(row[4] for row in csv.reader(f)))
```